# Facebook Login - Hybrid Apps

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, html, facebook-login

`UPDATE:`

In the end, I ended up imlementing using `apache cordova/phonegap` via Eclipse for android and xcode for iOS. This is the only solution that works on my preferred set up.

Link to download the plugin and documentation: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin

`Previous post:`

I would like to implement facebook login into my hybrid apps. I already did few research in facebook documentation but I haven't found anything that works. If you can provide me some tips, that would be very helpful. I will reward a bounty for someone who can tell me how to do it.

I don't want to go through Phonegap/cordova and other framework since it would need me a lot of time to study those framework.

`Hybrid apps - like native apps, run on the device, and are written with web technologies (HTML5, CSS and JavaScript). Hybrid apps run inside a native container, and leverage the device’s browser engine (but not the browser) to render the HTML and process the JavaScript locally. A web-to-native abstraction layer enables access to device capabilities that are not accessible in Mobile Web applications, such as the accelerometer, camera and local storage.`

If anyone has any solution and willing to help, please let me know.

I've tried Javascript SDK but no luck.

Code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'xxxx', // App ID
    channelUrl : '//xxxx/channel.html', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

  // Here we subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange JavaScript event. This event is fired
  // for any authentication related change, such as login, logout or session refresh. This means that
  // whenever someone who was previously logged out tries to log in again, the correct case below 
  // will be handled. 
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the     current
      // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
      // have logged in to the app.     
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app, so we call
      // FB.login() to prompt them to do so. 
      // In real-life usage, you wouldn't want to immediately prompt someone to login 
      // like this, for two reasons:
      // (1) JavaScript created popup windows are blocked by most browsers unless they 
      // result from direct interaction from people using the app (such as a mouse click)
      // (2) it is a bad experience to be continually prompted to login upon page load.
      FB.login();
    } else {
      // In this case, the person is not logged into Facebook, so we call the login() 
      // function to prompt them to do so. Note that at this stage there is no indication
      // of whether they are logged into the app. If they aren't then they'll see the Login
      // dialog right after they log in to Facebook. 
      // The same caveats as above apply to the FB.login() call here.
      FB.login();
    }
  });
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   /* js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"; */
   js.src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful. 
  // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases. 
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
  }
</script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses the JavaScript SDK to
  present a graphical Login button that triggers the FB.login() function when clicked.

  Learn more about options for the login button plugin:
  /docs/reference/plugins/login/ -->

<!-- <fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button> -->

<!-- End script of Facebook Login -->
```

Comment: The javascript SDK should work fine locally, except that if you're using the sample initialisation code you'll to specify http:// or https:// instead of the protocol-relative '//' example in the documentation

Comment: @Igy - I updated my post with my code. The problem is, I got this error message `Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.`. I doubt that this is because of the app domains and Mobile site URL. But what should I put in there? I currently put on Mobile Site URL and App domains:my host server name where I uploaded the channel file.

Comment: @Igy, I got this working only if I will use `localhost` or I upload my html file to my host server. Is there any other way? OR am I only missing an important app settings in there?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think you'd have to also implement your own user-base, and Facebook would simply be the access point into those.

Comment: which line does it refer to when it shows the error?

Comment: @T0X1C I'm using google chrome.

Comment: @Chad I don't really get what you mean. Can you explain further? Thanks.

Comment: @Rohit The error shows up during authentication. Please see second comment.

Comment: Is channel.html in the same domain?

Comment: ^that and also make sure the settings of the facebook app (from within facebook.com) match with the settings you put on the web app

Comment: @JunM Can you comment on what specific hybrid-app abstraction layer you're currently using, assuming it is an off-the-shelf solution?

Comment: have you tried intel XDK? software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/integrating-facebook-functionality-into-hybrid-apps-using-the-intel-xdk

Answer (score 0):

[image: Facebook app details]
Are you currently testing it from your local computer or hosting the HTML on a server?
if on a server - what is your domain?

1. update it on the app domains (see image)
2. update it on section "Website with Facebook Login"
3. for testing the issue, remove FB.api call from testAPI(). just put an alert.
4. test it from a standard browser. If it works - nothing is wrong with your FB definition.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `FB.Event.subscribe`

use **FB.getLoginStatus**

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }); 

  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });
```

Reference link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across a different solution which is working really well for me, and even better, no native code libraries! The trick here is to bypass the Facebook JavaScript SDK library and use the Facebook REST api endpoints directly.

I am using OpenFB javascript library (https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB) to make this job easier, rather than write the calls all myself, but you can do it either way. I've outlined the steps on how to get it to work below.

1) Create a Facebook app and update the URL settings under Basic and Advanced to allow callbacks using facebook or your local urls. Then copy the Facebook ID ready for the next step

[image]

2) If you haven't already, download and install Cordova to put the tools in your command line. Then navigate to your Sites folder and run the following commands to create the project and add your platforms:

```
cordova create your-project-name
cordova platform add ios
cordova platform add android
```

3)  Now we need to add a Cordova plugin to handle pop-up windows from facebook logins. To add a plugin use the command:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

4) Now we just need to download and configure OpenFB inside our new Cordova project. For this example we will just use the test page they provide, so download it from the OpenFB Github page and extract the files into your cordova project /www/ folder. After this open the index.html and edit the following line with your Facebook App ID from step 1:

```
openFB.init({appId: 'YOUR_FB_APP_ID'});
```

5) You should now be able to run the example and login using your local browser setup.

6) To test on iOS simulator you will need xCode installed then run the command:

```
cordova emulate ios
```

To test on an android emulator you will need the Android SDK installed and then run the command:

```
cordova emulate android
```

To test on an iOS device connected with a cable, run following command:

```
cordova run ios
```

To test on an Android device connected with a cable, run following command:

```
cordova run android
```